# plot.window error in loop for R creating basic plots

Tags: r, loops, plot

I apologize for not generating pseudo data for this question, but I think the problems I am facing are basic to most non novice individuals on this site. I am attempting to create a loop that plots a scatterplot of x and y for each value of a z variable.

```
x=rnorm(n=50)
y=rnorm(n=50)
z<-rep(c(1,2,3,4,5),10)
dataset <-cbind(x,y,z)
Dataset<-as.data.frame(dataset)
attach(Dataset)
jpeg()
z <-Dataset$z[1:5]
for(i in 1:5) {
    y<-y[z==i]
    x <-x[z==i]
    ARMAXpath<-file.path("C:", "Desktop", paste("myplot_", z[i], ".jpg", sep="")) 
    jpeg(file = ARMAXpath)
    TheTitle = paste("Scatter Plots", z[i])
    plot.new()
    plot.window(xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(5,10))
    plot(y,x)
    dev.off()
}
detach(Dataset)
```

No matter what I do I get the same `plot.window` error. I ran this code with and without attach. I ran it with and without `plot.window`. I also moved it in and outside the loop.

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

My question is how do I generate plots of two time series by a third variable in my dataset (i.e. region) write the output to a file folder as I have poorly attempted to do above?

Comment: This a probably a good example of why you should never use `attach`. Remove that (and the line `z <-Dataset$z[1:5]` which I think must just be an error) and refer to each variable specifically using `$` or `[[`.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you have that extra `jpeg` call before the for loop. That must be a mistake as well, right?

Answer (score 0):

Why not: consolidate all three plot calls into:

```
 plot(y,x, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(5,10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Some alternative code, using @DWin's comment:

```
x=rnorm(n=50)
y=rnorm(n=50)
z<-rep(c(1,2,3,4,5),10)
Dataset<-data.frame(x=x,y=y,z=z)

my.plot <- function(x,y,z){
    ARMAXpath<-file.path("C:", "Desktop", paste0("myplot_", z, ".jpg"))
    jpeg(file = ARMAXpath)
    plot(y,x, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(5,10))
    dev.off()
}

by(Dataset, Dataset$z, function(d) my.plot(d$x,d$y,unique(d$z)))
```